# How to register and get IUserIdentity from container in NancyFx?

Tags: authentication, ioc-container, nancy, structuremap3

I use FluentValidation with NancyFx. I want to validate some data against current context, exactly against current user. Unfortunately I can't find any example how to register and get back from container (I'm using StructureMap) such a informations.

Docs "The context should be available in most places of Nancy so it should never be an issue to get the identity of the user that is invoking the current request." but container doesn't have it at default.

Any links, directions?

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The context is request scoped - as is the user identity - and is passed into the RequestStartup method which you can override in your bootstrapper. The container is also passed into RequestStartup so you can register whatever you need per request and use the context when building the objects you register.

Comment: That's true. I found it. BUT... There is no any informations about identity. Context.CurrentUser is null because is created/mapped later. :(

Question is: is IContainer registered in container also scoped as per request (is it child container)? If Yes I can pull it and register my identity service when identity mapping is made (within IUserMapper).

Comment: I would think that IContainer is request scoped. Try it :)

Comment: @Jon I'm using Forms.

Comment: How about passing the context into your identity service? The identity will eventually be set on context, right? And probably before the service needs it, right?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines:

Register ICurrentContextProvider per request. ICurrentContextProvider can have only one property of IUserIdentity, although I would recommend to have make it with 2 explicit methods for set and get, so you can prevent double initialization, etc.

Make your IUserMapper (assuming its request scoped as well) to depend on ICurrentContextProvider, and after the mapping, set the property.

After that, any code which depends on the ICurrentContextProvider will have access to the property you set.